# How does coherence affect propagation of a light source?

Tags: optics, coherence

I have a light source with source width 150um. I need to propagate this in free space towards a lens of focal length z=4.5mm (the source is at this distance, z from the lens). The wavelength of the source is 650nm. I need to do this for sources with different amounts of coherence and see how the propagation differs - first for an incoherent source, then a fully coherent source and then sources with partial coherence. What method is generally used for this type of problem? I don't currently know how to define the sources. I started by looking at something along these lines in MATLAB:

```
sourcewidth = 150*10^-6; % width of source (m)

lambda = 650*10^-9; % wavelength of source (m)

focallength = 4.5*10^-3; focal length of lens and also distance from source to lens

k = 2*pi/lambda;

xallspace = (-150*10^-6):1*10^-6:(150*10^-6); % x space that the source occupies - no idea if this is correct

spacing = xallspace(2)-xallspace(1); % spacing of x sections

xlitspace = (-150*10^-6)/2:1*10^-6:(150*10^-6)/2; % section of space where source is

% Here some U0 needs to be defined to represent the light source - UNSURE WHAT TO INSERT HERE

plot(xallspace,real(U0),x0,imag(U0))

U1 = spacing*conv(U0,(1j*z./(lambda*(z^2+x0.^2))).*exp(-1j*sign(z)*k*sqrt(z^2+x0.^2))) % source after free space propagation
```

but am a bit unclear whether this is the right way to do it and how to define U0. Can anyone advise?

Comment: Your code is impossible to read.  This sounds like a problem for Fourier optics.

Comment: A very nice practical book for this kind of thing is *Computational Fourier Optics: A MATLAB Tutorial* by David Voelz.